# Returning a 4D array from a function in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, multidimensional-array, types, return-type

I am trying to return a 4D array of image data from a function call in MATLAB. I'm not very advanced in MATLAB and I don't know what type of data I have to return from the function. Here is my function:

```
function classimg = loadImages(classdir,ext)
    % create array of all images in directory
    neg = dir([classdir ext]);
    % get size of array (to loop through images)
    numFileNeg = max(size(neg));
    % create a 4D array to store our images
    classimg = zeros(51,51,3,numFileNeg);
    % loop through directory
    for i=1:numFileNeg
        classimg(:,:,:,i) = imread([myDir neg(i).name]);
    end
end
```

Here is the function call:

```
negativeImgs = loadImages("C:\Users\example\Documents\TrainingImages\negatives\","*.jpg");
```

I cannot find any online documentation for the return type? Does anyone know what this would be? `classimg` is populated correctly so the code inner works.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is? MATLAB is not statically typed, the return value can be of any type. So just run the function and look at the return value! That said, AFAIK `imread` will return an MxNx3 array of uint8 values, so your return value will likley be MxNx3xJ of uint8.

Comment: Also it would be better form to use `numFileNeg = numel(neg)` or `numFileNeg = length(neg)` rather than `numFileNeg = max(size(neg))`

Answer (score 2):

You initialize classimg to be a 51x51x3xnumFileNeg matrix of zeros.  You use the zeros function, so the datatype is double.  To see this clearly, call your function from the command window, and then type "whos" to see both the size and datatype of classimg.

Answer (score 0):

[As Mike correctly points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47702192/52738), since you initialize `classimg` using [`zeros`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zeros.html), and the default data type is [`double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html), your image data will be converted to double from whatever data type [`imread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html) returns ([often `uint8`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/image-types.html)).

If you would like `classimg` to be the same data type as your images (which I'm assuming all have the same type), you can load one image, get its [class](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/class.html), and initialize `classimg` with that specific class. Here's how you could rewrite your function:

```
function classimg = loadImages(classdir, ext)
  neg = dir(fullfile(classdir, ext));
  numFileNeg = numel(neg);
  tempImage = imread(fullfile(classdir, neg(1).name));
  classimg = zeros(51, 51, 3, numFileNeg, class(tempImage));
  classimg(:, :, :, 1) = tempImage;
  for i = 2:numFileNeg
    classimg(:, :, :, i) = imread(fullfile(classdir, neg(i).name));
  end
end
```

Note that I made a couple of other changes. I used [`fullfile`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) instead of concatenation of the directory and file names, since it handles any issues with [file separators](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filesep.html) for you. I also used [`numel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/numel.html) to get the number of files [as Justin suggested in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47695168/return-4d-array-from-a-function-in-matlab#comment82350932_47695168).